# files in C# - "file is used by another process"

Tags: c#, .net

I have following code:

```
private void askforlocation()
        {
            if (File.Exists("location.txt"))
            {
                System.IO.StreamReader loc = new System.IO.StreamReader("location.txt");
                string loca = loc.ReadToEnd();
                if (loca != "")
                {
                    int index = comboBox1.FindString(loca);
                    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = index;
                }
                else
                {
                    label6.Text = "Please select the location!";
                }
                loc.Close();
            }
            else label6.Text = "Please select the location!";        
        }
```

It is supposed to read value "location" from the file and put it to the combo box, which works ok.

I run this script on Form1_Load.

Now, I have another script:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("location.txt", value);
}
```

This one is supposed to record the choice so that user doesn't need to enter location every time.

What is happening is when I start a program, so the value is already set, then I try to change it (so that theoretically it should overwrite the previous one), but I get an exception, saying that file is already being used by another process.

I do close the file after I used it. I also tried `FILE.DISPOSE`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what's happening here is that this code:

```
if (loca != "")
{
    int index = comboBox1.FindString(loca);
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = index;
}
```

is causing the `SelectedIndexChanged` event to be raised on the combobox. When that event is raised, `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` is called, and that method again tries to access `location.txt`.

To fix, I would first change the code in `askforlocation` to something like this:

```
if (File.Exists("location.txt"))
{
    var loca = string.Emtpy;
    using(var loc = new System.IO.StreamReader("location.txt"))
    {
         loca = loc.ReadToEnd();
    }
    ....
}
```

since there's no need to keep the file open for longer than necessary (note that the `using` block will call the `Dispose()` method on the `StreamReader` when it exits, which in turn will call the `Close()` method). After that, I'd consider coming up with a way to keep the event from being fired when you set the selected index on the combobox (maybe use a flag or unwire/rewire the event handler).

Comment: It's important to point out to anybody reading this answer that wrapping the file reading in a "using" block implicitly calls the Close() method.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're changing the index of your combobox, thus writing to the same file before closing it. Call loca.Close() before writing to the file again.

Answer (score 1):

comboBox1.SelectedIndex = index;
this will fire the event SelectedIndexChanged, so invoke the Close() method right behind ReadToEnd():

```
private void askforlocation()
        {
            if (File.Exists("location.txt"))
            {
                System.IO.StreamReader loc = new System.IO.StreamReader("location.txt");
                string loca = loc.ReadToEnd();
                loc.Close();//move that code to here
                if (loca != "")
                {
                    int index = comboBox1.FindString(loca);
                    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = index;
                }
                else
                {
                    label6.Text = "Please select the location!";
                }
                //loc.Close();
            }
            else label6.Text = "Please select the location!";        
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this line `loc.Close();`  before setting the index of the combo box because the event is being raised earlier than you think.

Answer (score 0):

You never need to call file.Close() or file.Dispose().

Please use a using statement ALWAYS (or mostly) when using a class that implements IDisposable.  It will call the Dispose method for you.

```
using(System.IO.StreamReader loc = new System.IO.StreamReader("location.txt"))
{
    string loca = loc.ReadToEnd();
}
```